# Javascript slice off last character if there are 2 of them

Tags: javascript

how to cut off second sign if there is a second sign ?? some times id is ....5a and 5b and i need to cut of the 'a' and 'b'

JS

```
$(".mieszkanie").click(function() {
        var num = this.id.replace(/c_10_0/, "");
        var n = num.length;
        if (n = 2) { 
            [than cut second sign]
        }
        $('.pdf').attr({ 
            href: "img/rzuty/mieszkania/pietro10rzuty/00" + num + ".pdf"
        });
        $('.karta img').attr({ 
            src: "img/rzuty/mieszkania/pietro10rzuty/00" + num + ".png",
            alt: "mieszkanie 00" + num
        });
    });
```

HTML

```
<div id="rzuty10p" class="rzuty">
            <span id="c_10_01" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_10_02" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_10_03" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_10_04" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_10_06" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_10_05a" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_10_05b" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
        </div>
```

Comment: please tell me what a 'second sign' is? or give some example input :)

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking right now. Could you provide sample input and expected output? That may help make it clearer what the question is about.

Comment: 1, 2, 3, 4 ... is ok but some times i have 5a and 5b and i need only 5

Comment: Agreed - this makes no sense. Define 'second sign'. Please edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `substr` method to get only the first character:

```
var num = this.id.replace(/c_10_0/, "").substr(0, 1);
```

Comment: super cool man, apparently some people do not need further explanation, thx mate